# Reading X,Y from mouse click in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I am trying to build a tool that will precisely (10digit, eg: AA1234512345) identify British National Grid (BNG) by clicking on a map. The ArcGis default tool can only display 6digit (eg. AA123123). 
I have already written a code that calculates required BNG for point/line/polygon within a shapefile/feature class and recording it in an attribute table (I hope to cannibalise it).

I know that Arc 10.1 introduced something like onMouseDownMap [http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40730] (and Python Add-in Wizard) which seems to solve my problem but I am using Arc 10.0…

Is there anything in Arc 10.0 similar to onMouseDownMap? How to read coordinates (X, Y) from mouse click.

In brief my tool should work like:

Click on ‘identify’ button --> click on a map --> pop up window with BNG

My knowledge of python is rather limited… but I am fighting.

Answer (score 4):

Arc 10.0 can not create a Python Add-In. But, you can use VBA to create a UITool (you need to get VBA License), or you can create an Add-In with Visual Studio.

Comment: I was expecting that kind of answer…  I had a small hope that there is python way of doing that, as VBA is a black magic for me. Thank you anyway.